# DS2431+ EEPROM Toner cartridge Information

Tags: eeprom

I have an Toner Cartridge with EEPROM of model DS2431.

I am able to read the bit data from the eeprom using Arduino OneWire library.

I am also able to write to the eeprom.

But when I write to it I am not able to write it again. And also when I erase it, it has same issue that I cannot write to it again.

I want to know that. Is DS2431 Eeprom only write once?

If no how can I rewrite to it again, even after erasing it.

Comment: Read the datasheet

Comment: Can you believe that many countries have draconian laws that make asking and answering questions such as this illegal.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the EEPROM has been write-protected. You should check the contents at [address 0x80-0x83](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS2431.pdf): values 0x55h and 0xAAh indicate write-protection and EPROM-emulation modes respectively. Both modes disallow you to erase protected pages.

Comment: @RishabhKalkundri That type of information dump should go in the _question_, not hidden away in the comments.